# C# - An Unhandled Win 32 Exception Occured in exe[Process Id]

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

My c# windows application is crashing abruptly and following application exception was logged by the DR.watson

Application exception occurred:
        App: C:\Program Files\InstalltionFolder\Application.exe (pid=296)
        When: 5/24/2012 @ 11:13:00.141
        Exception number: e0434f4d 
()

Your help would be much appreciated.

Rgds
P

Comment: Run the application in debug mode to get the exception info, or maybe the exception is logged?

Comment: You need to be more specific... There could be a lot of reasons why it fails: .NET framework is not installed, loading one of the native dlls failure, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to debug your application inside Visual Studio. Load it up, build it in Debug mode, and press F5 or select Debug -> Start Debugging from the menu.

Then do what you did before to get the exception. Visual Studio will 'trap' the exception and hopefully display more information to you regarding the problem.

Without knowing the exception code, not much more help can be given.

Comment: Hi The below is the exception that i found in dr.watson can you help on the same Application exception occurred: App: C:\Program Files\InstalltionFolder\Application.exe (pid=296) When: 5/24/2012 @ 11:13:00.141 Exception number: e0434f4d ()

Comment: This post might help with that error: http://tomfaust.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/appcrash-exception-code-e0434f4d.html

Comment: Hi All thanks it was due to the code issue which is resolved. Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can check your register base

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger
```

and you must have permission

Comment: Hi All thanks it was due to the code issue which is resolved. Thanks all for the help